# Algorithm : Remove duplicate elements from linked list

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

Give a linked list [unsorted], remove consecutive duplicate elements :

input :

1 2 3 5 5 6 6 3 2 7

output :

1 7

- after first iteration 3 and 3 become consecutive duplicate, and after 2nd iteration 2 and 2 become consecutive duplicates

Programming language is not a concern, java/c/c++, anything will do.
Using extra memory is not preferred, no extra stacks or queues, need to be done in one iteration.

Comment: First what is your programming language, and also what have you tried?

Comment: Traverse the list and use an external stack to keep track of the current predecessors.

Comment: See [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list/)

Comment: This is not possible in one pass without any extra memory to remove duplicate of an unsorted linked list. If the linked list is sorted, one pass `O(n)` will be okay. And if its unsorted, then extra memory `O(n)` for hashtable is required.

Comment: What could be best without sorting and without extra space ?

Comment: `O(n^2)` pass is required without sorting and extra space

Comment: Sorting will require `O(nlog n)` and then `O(n)` pass will be fast than `O(n^2)` pass

Comment: Sorting will losse the order, and then we can't know whether they were consecutive.

Comment: To do it in a single pass, you need a doubly linked list.

Comment: The problem may not have a unique result. Take for example `1 2 2 3 3 2`: if we remove the 2's first we end up with `1 2` but if we remove the 3's first the result is `1`.

Comment: @Henry Interesting point, but should the algorithm remove an entire sequence of 3 or more duplicates, or only two at a time? If it's only two at a time, then your example always ends with `1 2`.

Comment: @user3386109 yep, thats a bit ambiguous in the description.

Comment: @Henry I agree, so I assumed only two at a time, since that makes the answer easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in a single pass with just 4 integer variable like this in java :

```
int current = integers.getFirst();//shows the current number we are reading from the list.
int past = current;               //shows the last number we read.
int iterator = 0;                 //shows where we are.
int NumOfRemoveProcess = 0;       //shows number of nodes we are currently removing.

while (integers.size() > iterator+1){
    iterator++;                      
    current = integers.get(iterator);//getting next value

    if(past == current){             //checking if two(or more consecutive elements are duplicated)
        NumOfRemoveProcess ++;       //shows the number of duplication that we saw.
        integers.remove(iterator);   //remove the new duplicated number.
        iterator --;                 //set iterator after remove.
    }

    else if(NumOfRemoveProcess>0){   //if we removed number in the previous turn.
        iterator--;                  //remove the first duplicated number.
        integers.remove(iterator);
        iterator --;                 //set iterator
        NumOfRemoveProcess = 0;
        past = integers.get(iterator);
    }
    else
        past = current;
}
```

while integers is a linked list of your integers. [Here](http://ideone.com/f3RyX8) is a working version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in a single pass, you need a [doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list), that is each *node* needs pointers to the *previous* and *next* nodes.

Using the example from the question, when the *current node* (indicated by the ^) reaches the first 5,

```
1 2 3 5 5 6 6 3 2 7
      ^
```

you remove both 5's leaving the *current node* pointing to the 3

```
1 2 3 6 6 3 2 7
    ^
```

The 3 doesn't match the next *node*, so after advancing to the next *node*, you find and remove the duplicate 6's, and again leave the *current node* pointing at the 3

```
1 2 3 3 2 7
    ^
```

This time the 3 matches the next *node*, so the 3's are removed leaving the *current node* pointing at the 2

```
1 2 2 7
  ^
```

Remove the 2's and you're done.  To summarize, any time the algorithm removes a duplicate, the *current node* takes the value of *previous* pointer from the first *node* that was deleted.